# Proving Deligne's formula

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, schemes

If $A$ is a noetherian ring, $X = \text{Spec } A$, and $U = X - V(\mathfrak{a})$ for $\mathfrak{a}$ an ideal of $A$, then the following formula holds for any $A$-module $M$ (with associated $\mathcal{O}_X$-module $\tilde{M}$):
$$\Gamma(U,\tilde{M}) \cong \text{colim}_n \hom_A(\mathfrak{a}^n,M).$$
I've tried to prove this result by showing $\Gamma(U,\tilde{M})$ satisfies the required universal property. To that end, I defined a cocone to $\Gamma(U,\tilde{M})$ from the $\hom_A(\mathfrak{a}^n,M)$, taking
$$h_n: \hom_A(\mathfrak{a}^n,M) \to \Gamma(U,\tilde{M}), \quad h_n(f)(\mathfrak{p}) = \frac{f(x)}{x} \in M_\mathfrak{p},$$
where $\mathfrak{p} \in D(x) = V(x)^c$ for $x \in \mathfrak{a}^n$. It's easy to check that $h_n(f)$ is a well-defined section over $U$.

The next step is to show that for any other cocone $(C, \gamma_n)$, there is a unique mediating morphism $\theta: \Gamma(U,\tilde{M}) \to C$. Finding $\theta$ should depend on realising an arbitrary $g \in \Gamma(U,\tilde{M})$ as a value of some $h_n$, but this is where I've become stuck.

Are my maps $h_n$ wrong? If not, how to produce $g = h_n(f)$? Reductions so far: since $A$ is noetherian, $g$ can be represented as a tuple $\left ( \frac{m_1}{x_1^r}, \dots, \frac{m_k}{x_k^r} \right )$, where $m_i \in M$, the $x_i$ generate $\mathfrak{a}$, and $r$ is large.

Comment: If $\mathfrak{a}$ is principal obviously you're done. If $\mathfrak{a}$ is not principal I don't think I understand what your map $h_n$ is. I think you may find it easier to work with the ideals $\mathfrak{b}_r = (x_1^r, ..., x_k^r)$, for $x_1,..., x_k$ generators of $\mathfrak{a}$. These are "cofinal" for the $\mathfrak{a}^n$, i.e. the direct limits of the homs from the $\mathfrak{a}^n$ and from the $\mathfrak{b}_r$ are equal. Your representation of a section $g$ really comes from localising away from the $\mathfrak{b}_r$'s. Also, $g$ is a sum of things in $M$ over $U$, not a tuple of them.

Comment: @Mr. Chip Could you clarify what you mean by $h_n$?

Comment: Hey guys, thanks for your input. My $h_n$ maps send the hom $f: \mathfrak{a}^n \to M$ to a section whose value at $\mathfrak{p} \in U$ is $f(x)/x \in M_\mathfrak{p}$, where $x$ is any element of $\mathfrak{a}^n - \mathfrak{p}$. Notice that such an $x$ must exist, since $\mathfrak{p} \in U$, and that if $y$ is another choice, $f(x)/x = f(y)/y$ by $A$-linearity. Does that make sense?

Comment: I see, now I understand. What I said before was mistaken. You're writing $g$ as glued from sections $m_i/x_i^r$ over the principal open sets $x_i \neq 0$. Then by definition you have $x_j^r m_i = x_i^r m_j$ over the intersection $x_i x_j \neq 0$. So the element $g$ is picked out by the map $f: \mathfrak{a}^r \to M$ which takes the generator $x_i^r$ to $m_i$. Then your $h_r(f)$ agrees with $g$ on these intersections. Now I want to look at the ideals $(x_1^r, ..., x_k^r)$ because they have a lot fewer syzygies to think about! I guess if you stay with $\mathfrak{a}^n$ then you look at triple...

Comment: ...intersections etc to check that $f$ makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rodney Sharp and Markus Brodmann's contribution towards helping people to understand the Deligne isomorphism is Section 20.1 of the Second Edition of their book "Local cohomology" [here](http://bookzz.org/dl/2292455/9edeb7), but see also 2.3.2.

Brodmann, M. P.; Sharp, R. Y. **Local cohomology.** An algebraic introduction with geometric applications. Second edition. Cambridge Studies in Advanced Mathematics, 136. *Cambridge University Press, Cambridge,* 2013. xxii+491 pp.

The family $(h_n)$ of maps you suggest is alright. This family implies a map$$h: D_\mathfrak{a}(M) \to \Gamma(U, \tilde{M})$$which is the inverse of the isomorphism $\nu_{\mathfrak{a}, M}$ of 20.1.14. You will recognize this, if you consider the local family $\delta$ on page 449. (Clearly, in your case, the situation is slightly simpler, as you consider the standard affine case, whereas the hypothesis 20.1.2 concern a more general situation.)

You are actually asking whether $h$ is surjective. To prove this, you will need the fact, that for each $g \in \Gamma(U, \tilde{M})$ there is some $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that (in the notations used in 20.1.14) $\mathfrak{a}^n g \subseteq \mathrm{Im}(\varepsilon^U_M)$. In the more general setting of the standard hypotheses 20.1.2 this is shown in 20.1.10.

> Can you elaborate on how exactly to use $\mathfrak{a}^n g \subseteq \text{Im}(\varepsilon_M^U)$? Clearly I'd like to use it to construct a map $f: \mathfrak{a}^n \to M$.

Let $g \in \Gamma(U, \tilde{M}) = \tilde{M}(U)$. Then by 20.1.10 there is some $k \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\mathfrak{a}^kg \subseteq \varepsilon_M^U(M)$. By 2.1.8(iii) we have $\text{Ker}(\varepsilon_M^U) = \Gamma_\mathfrak{a}(M)$ and so, we may identify$$\varepsilon_M^U(M) = \overline{M} := M/\Gamma_\mathfrak{a}(M).$$There is a finitely generated $R$-submodule $N \subseteq M$ such that$$(N + \Gamma_\mathfrak{a}(M))/\Gamma_\mathfrak{a}(M) = \mathfrak{a}^k g\subseteq \overline{M}.$$By Artin-Rees, there is some $t \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\mathfrak{a}^tN \cap \Gamma_\mathfrak{a}(M) = 0$. Set $n = k + t$. Then, we get$$\mathfrak{a}^ng = (\mathfrak{a}^t N + \Gamma_\mathfrak{a}(M))/\Gamma_\mathfrak{a}(M) = (\mathfrak{a}^tN)/(\mathfrak{a}^tN \cap \Gamma_\mathfrak{a}(M)) = (\mathfrak{a}^tN)/0 = \mathfrak{a}^tN \subseteq M.$$Hence we have a map$$f \in \text{Hom}_R(\mathfrak{a}^n, M), \quad x \mapsto f(x) := xg \quad(\forall x \in \mathfrak{a}^n).$$In your notations we get:$$h_n(f)_\mathfrak{p} := {{f(x)}\over x} = {{xg}\over x} = g_\mathfrak{p} \text{ for all }\mathfrak{p} \in U \text{ and all }x \in \mathfrak{a}^n \setminus \mathfrak{p}.$$This shows that $h_n(f) = g$.

You see, that my former hint was incomplete (which I was aware of), as I did not mention the equality $\text{Ker}(\varepsilon_M^U) = \Gamma_\mathfrak{a}(M)$ of 20.1.8(iii).

Here are a few additional hints for the reading of the proof of 20.1.10 in the ordinary affine case (with $S = R$ and $T = \text{Spec}(R)$). The arguments become slightly simpler than in the book, but they base on the same ideas. Do not forget, that the situation in the book covers much more, for example the case of (multi-)projective schemes $T$...

You represent $g$ by$$\left({{m_1}\over{s_1}}, \ldots, {{m_r}\over{s_r}}\right), \text{ with }s_1, \ldots, s_r \in \mathfrak{a} \text{ and }\bigcup_{i = 1}^r (\text{Spec}(R) \setminus \text{Var}((s_i))) = U$$so that for each $\mathfrak{p} \in U := \text{Spec}(R) \setminus \text{Var}(\mathfrak{a})$ there is an $i$ such that $s_i \ni \mathfrak{p}$ and moreover, if $s_i \ni \mathfrak{p}$, then it holds in $M_\mathfrak{p}$ that $g_\mathfrak{p} = {{m_i}\over{s_i}}$ (see 20.8.1(i)).

The essential point is to show that there is some $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that$$s_i^ng \in \varepsilon_M^U(M) \text{ for all }i = 1, 2, \ldots, r.\tag*{$(*)$}$$This is shown in the first 12 lines on page 446, on use of 20.1.19. I suggest that you read this and the proof of 20.1.9 in the book and translate it step by step to your "classical" situation in which $S = R$ and $T = \text{Spec}(R)$. I suggest this, as this reading will face you with arguments which are of basic significance if you want to learn algebraic geometry.

Let $\mathfrak{b} := \sum_{i = 1}^r Rs_i^n$. Then by $(*)$ you get$$\mathfrak{b}g \subseteq \varepsilon_M^U(M).$$It is not hard to see, that $\text{Var}(\mathfrak{b}) \subseteq \text{Var}(\mathfrak{a})$ so that $\mathfrak{a}^k \subseteq \mathfrak{b}$ for some positive integer $k$ (cf. line 14 and 15 on page 446). Therefore $\mathfrak{a}^kg \in \varepsilon_M^U(M)$.

Comment: Hello Harambe, thanks for your answer. Can you elaborate on how exactly to use $\mathfrak{a}^n g \subseteq \text{Im}(\varepsilon_M^U)$? Clearly I'd like to use it to construct a map $f: \mathfrak{a}^n \to M$.

Comment: Thanks for the fantastic additions. I think the piece I was missing was the use of Artin–Rees.

Comment: I was reading this proof and I'm missing something about the use of Artin-Rees, aren't we using somehow that there is a power $\mathfrak{a}^n$ s.t. $\mathfrak{a}^n \Gamma_{\mathfrak{a}}(M)=0$? Why is this the case? I mean in principle it should depend on each element...

Comment: @Oromis You should use Artin-Rees on $N$ together with its submodule $N\cap \Gamma_{\mathfrak{a}}(M)$ because $N$ is finitely generated.